# Give a default value for shared pointer argument

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

The following code gives a compilation error in VS2010, which support shared_ptr and make_shared function. Why and how to correct it?

```
#include <memory>

class A
{
    A(std::shared_ptr<int> p = std::make_shared<int>())   // error is at this line
    {}
};
```

It shows "make_shared" is not a member of "global namespace".

Comment: If that single ':' was a typo, then something's wrong with VC++. Clang compiles it.

Comment: `ideone` compiles it as well (in C++11 mode)

Comment: Seems like a bug indeed. See the linked answer